# Active Directory(On Premises AD not Azure AD) authentcation with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, xamarin

i am working on PCL xamarin forms application which has Login form, in order to gain access into this app user credentials needs to get match with local active directory user. i have researched a lot but did not found any solution out there.

I also have one web api which user may have access to if his/her credential gets match with AD. which provides data to app after gaining access to this app.

Is it possible to add code to authenticate user with AD using ASP.net web API? if yes How ?

Can someone provide a sample of flow or code so i may have idea how flow works in this case?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to do authentication from the code level between Xamarin and On-prime AD. But in order to do that you may need to configure your AD to accept the authentication from code level.

[This is a link](http://vinochsnv.blogspot.com/2017/06/connectivity-between-xamarin-forms-and.html), I have written on how the Open ID protocol used to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding on my post,

Comment: Just one more question i got my client id by registering my app on Microsoft Registration Portal, But, By any chance could you please tell me how do i get client secret? to add into my http request?

Comment: Microsoft Azure AD will provide you the key at the time of registering. You must copy the key since the key will be hidden after few minutes. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal